# I am not able to add a bounty to my question

Tags: support, questions, bounties

I want to add a bounty to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490940/what-precautions-should-you-take-when-a-senior-employee-leaves) on SO. I have checked threads on Meta but I am not able to find how to add a bounty to my question.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I am not able to include the link of the searched meta thread, because I am a new user here.

Comment: You have to wait two days before you can add a bounty. This has been covered many times.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty.

Comment: @mmyers : thanks.. and sorry. i should have serached it more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait at least 48 hours to start a bounty.

[Read about bounties.](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)

Comment: Reading is hard.  Can't you beam the information directly into my pea-sized brain?